# Firebase notifications are not sent in an Azure Function

Tags: c#, firebase, azure, azure-functions

We are developing a system where we need an event to be read from an Event Hubs queue, processed with Azure functions, and a push notification sent through Firebase.

When we debug this system in local mode outside of Azure it works perfectly, the notifications arrive and the responses we get when we call the firebase service are the usual ones, for example:

"projects/magonclabfb-57b13/messages/0:1695297973467228%67026b8f67026b8f"

```
        string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);

        return true;
```

Our Azure functions service is not within any subnets and does not have connection restrictions.

[image]

I suspect that the problem comes from the fact that from within Azure there is some connection problem with the Firebase service but I don't know how to solve it.

Another test we have done is that the same code in an AppService works perfectly.

Has anyone dealt with this problem?

Comment: I have added a trace with a try catch and it appears that the "response" object is null when run within Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution to the problem.

We make the call to Firebase by creating the connection object using the Firebase libraries for .NET. Sometimes the object that is instantiated as FirebaseApp is initialized to null, I understand that only one instance of that object should exist at a time and the asynchronous nature of the function could not handle this problem well.

We have chosen to create the notification by making a REST call to the Firebase API and we have solved the problem

```
GoogleCredential gc = GoogleCredential.FromJson(googleJson);
string tok = await gc.CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform").UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();

HttpClient httpCli = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxxx-57b13/messages:send"), };
httpCli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tok);
var content = new StringContent(m, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpCli.PostAsync("", content);
```